# firebase parent id returned instead of child id

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase, I am using ionic for the first time as well to develop a chat application. I have a database with a similar structure as shown below

```
tutors:
"Ben Clarke":
    email:"ben@yahoo.com"
    name: ben clarke
"James Gall":
   email:james@yahoo.com
   name: james gal
```

I am trying to get the Id of the tutors using the email. I have tried using the guide that I have found here and on firebase doc to do this:

```
`firebase.database().ref('tutors').orderByChild('email').equalTo(this.myTutor)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    var records = snapshot.key;
    var chilkkey= snapshot.val();
    this.tutorID=records;
    this. uid = chilkkey;
  })
```

`I want the result to give me 'Ben Clarke' the child id but instead it returns 'tutors' which is the parent id. Please, any idea on what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

If you then on the snapshot request the `key`, it's the key of the location that you originally ran the query on. To get the key of the specific child/children that were matched by the query, you need to loop over the result:

```
firebase.database().ref('tutors').orderByChild('email').equalTo(this.myTutor)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      console.log(child.key);
    });
  })
```